# How to package and deploy a DEB without any assumptions about dependencies installed on the target machine

Tags: apt, python, dependencies, deb

I am creating a DEB package for installation by external systems. At this early stage of development the DEB package consists of custom-developed Python wheels. These wheels depend on:

- System binary packages such as Cairo and GTK, that one would normally `apt install`, and
- Multiple Python wheels such a Matplotlib, available on PyPi.

Because I cannot make any assumptions about what is available on the third machine I need to somehow handle all dependencies. The first dependencies I encountered are pip and python. Because I [cannot `apt install` from the postinst script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641896/181783), I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Are these dependencies shipped with the DEB or something similar?

Comment: Define your dependencies in the deb package's control file. Dependencies must be other debs, not pips nor snaps nor anything else. Use your postinst script to set up your venv, install your wheels, etc.

Comment: So the dependencies should be listed in the control file and the postinst script should install the wheels. Got it. Thanks. (I don't need a venv.)